# Is there a package containing Apache PostgreSQL Perl for Windows?

Tags: windows, postgresql, apache, perl

I am looking for a package containig Apache Web server, PostgreSQL database and Perl for Windows (7, 10). Does anybody know such a package, possibly portable?

Comment: I don't think there is a single package for all of these, but all three components have Windows installers. I suggest using a package manager like https://scoop.sh/ though

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so, but those sorts of bundles are not as necessary as they once were. They're no longer as wielded together. Instead, get the pieces.

- [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) which comes with PostgreSQL drivers and compilers and everything you need for Perl development.
- [PostgreSQL for Windows](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/)
- [Apache for Windows](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html)

I'd recommend skipping Apache unless you specifically need it, it's likely quite a bit more complex than you need. Instead, write web server generic code using [Plack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plack_(software)). Use a Perl web server for development, and then the application can be deployed to whatever web server you'd like for production. Using a Perl web framework such as [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/) will make that all much simpler.